# solr facet - count of terms across multiple fields

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

Is there a way to run facet query on multiple fields and get total count of each terms across those fields. Currently when I use `facet.field=NAME&facet.field=TITLE` then my result set have separate count of terms for each. e.g. computer,2000 for NAME fields and computer,500 for TITLE. Is there a way to get computer, 2500 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On way (not sure if it's the best way) is to create an copyfield and merge Title and Name into that field.
something like this in your schema.xml

```
 <field name="FCOUNT" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
  [...]
 <copyField source="NAME" dest="FCOUNT"/>
 <copyField source="TITLE" dest="FCOUNT"/>
```

Now you can use `facet.field=FCOUNT`